# read cookies in front (Reactjs) that comes from nodejs

Tags: reactjs, session-cookies, google-authentication

i need to get cookies(it's a token) which has been defined in a node js Route file to my front, because i need to check infos of this token to show data if it's a user or admin.

THis is some code of the cookies :

```
// auth with google+
router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    ]
}));
// callback route for google to redirect to
// hand control to passport to use code to grab profile info
router.get('/auth/google/callback*', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    if(req.user){
        console.log(req.user);
        res.cookie('token', req.user);
        return res.redirect(config.clientURL);
    }
    else{
        console.log('error');
        return res.redirect(config.clientURL);
    }
});
```

```
// auth with faceboook
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
// callback route for facebook to redirect to
// hand control to passport to use code to grab profile info
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback*', passport.authenticate('facebook'), (req, res) => {
    console.log("je suis dans la route callback");
    if(req.user){
        console.log(req.user);
        res.cookie('token', req.user);
        return res.redirect(config.clientURL);
    }
    else{
        console.log('error');
        return res.redirect(config.clientURL);
    }
});
```

Edit :

i did this :

```
const auth_head =  document.cookie.split('.')[0];
        const auth_payload =  document.cookie.split('.')[1];
        const auth_signature =  document.cookie.split('.')[2];
        var auth_token = auth_head + "." + auth_payload + "." + auth_signature;

 console.log(JSON.parse( auth_head));
            console.log(JSON.parse( auth_payload));
            console.log(JSON.parse( auth_signature));
```

but i got this error : 
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Thank you

Comment: Hi there! You can access the cookies data from Javascript by using `document.cookie`; however, if your server is setting the cookie using the `httpOnly` flag (which is extremely good advice for security reasons) you won't be able to access the cookie from JS in your client; it will still exist, but you can't access the data. I will show an example below with a suggestion on how you can do what you need.

Comment: can you give me an example how to use it please ?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, it's good advice to use `httpOnly` flag when setting cookies; this means that you need another strategy to return the user data.

**Option 1**: One easier to implement way could be: After your server redirects the client to let's say `/logged-in`, you can fetch the user data from let's say `/api/userinfo`; the response should a json containing the user info; you should use that json to store the information in your client using `localStorate.setItem(...)`. This is the classic and more used way to store your user data in the client.

Example Server (Create an endpoint that returns the logged-in user info):

```
// Server endpoint that returns user info
router.get('/api/userinfo', 
passport.authenticate(your_strategy_here), 
(req, res) => {
  res.json({ name: req.user.name, role: req.user.role }); // Return just what you need
})
```

Example Client (Create a component that requests the user info from the new server endpoint):

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch('/api/userinfo')
  .then( res => res.json() )
  .then( user => localStorate.setItem('user', user);
}
```

**Option 2**: Give Google a URL which is resolved by the client, and then have the client send the request to `/auth/facebook/callback`; then have the server do `res.json(user)`, instead of the doing the redirect.

`Google -> /your-client-app/auth/callback`

`Client -> /auth/facebook/callback`

Option 2 is my advice, however, Option 1 may be more straight forward for your current setup.

**Option 3**: Disable httpOnly when setting the cookie, there are security concerns when doing this and it's not meant to be done like that in production apps.

```
res.cookie('token', req.user, { httpOnly: false });
```

And then on your client, you can use the following data to check the cookies.

```
const cookieData = document.cookie;
console.log(cookieData)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i don't know how to manage that, i mean ..
it's the dev who set up these routes, i neef to get this cookie and extrat data from it

Comment: I just added a more complete example for Option 1 (the easier one).

Comment: I also added an "Option 3" in case you want to go with an even simpler solution (but risky in production!)

Comment: thank you Davo, but am not using LocalStorage, the backend has used a cookies to set the token in nodejs as i decribed above, i just need to get it in front and extrat data from it to make some conditions. Hope it's clear :(

Comment: Hey @mitsu, yeah I understand. Just a clarification: localStorage is used in the client (not the backend) to store data your app may need. If you only need to get the data in your client, the try Option 3 and use `document.cookie` in your client to read your cookies.

Comment: yes i did that by how can i extrat data from the token i got with document.cookie please ? :)

Comment: Oh well, that depends on what you are storing; here's a small snippet to get a specific cookie value: https://gist.github.com/smievoll/1505383, but then depending on the value of the cookie you may need to parse it with the right technique; in your case it may be JSON.parse( the_cookie_value ).

Comment: i got this kind of result <hen i use document.cookie : 
eyJhY2NvdW50Ijp7InByZW5vbSI6ImFjaGUiLCJub20iOiJtZSIsInRlbCI6IjAyNjc2NTQ1NDMiLCJkYXRlQ3JlYXRpb24iOiIyMDE5LTExLTMwVDE4OjE4OjU0LjU4OVoiLCJkYXRlbmFpc3NhbmNlIjpudWxsLCJyZXNldHBhc3N3b3JkdG9rZW4iOm51bGwsInJlc2V0cGFzc3dvcmRleHBpcmVzIjpudWxsLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsImVuYWJsZSI6dHJ1ZSwiYWNjZXB0Q0dVIjpmYWxzZSwiYWNjZXB0Q29va2llcyI6ZmFsc2UsIl9pZCI6IjVkZTJiNDMzMWIwMWE1Nzc4MGEwNGZjZSIsImVtYWlsIjoibWUuYWNoZW1sYWxAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIkMmIkMTAkc016N2NhQ042UTFyUGt...

Comment: please take a look to my Edit